# How to change server url while application is in production phase?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sparkle

I have implemented **autoupdate** feature in my cocoa app using `Sparkle` framework. It is updating my product successfully. The steps which I am following are.

I am calling an url of .xml file which stored in the server. From my application .xml file calling my product which exists in same folder in server.

Now I have to put my application and xml in some different server for some reasons. In this case when user will check application update, he will not able update, because the url will unable to locate the xml file(now which exist in different server).

So in this case how can I update my Application?
Is there any approach by which I can change url of xml file dynamically while my product is in production phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to supply one version via the old URL that contains the new URL in its plist. Alternatively you can mod rewrite the old URL to the new URL on the server.